# Cross-Origin Read Blocking using Sleepy Mongoose

Tags: angular, mongodb, rest, http, sleepy-mongoose

I'm working on an Angular project.

I'm trying to make a GET request to a Sleepy Mongoose REST server.

I'm able to make the request and see the response with

> curl -X GET http://localhost:27080/Annotations/Manuscripts/_find

another solution that worked for me is running chrome.exe with

> --disable-web-security

But when trying to make the GET request with -

```
public fetchFromDB() {
    return this._http.get('http://localhost:27080/Annotations/Manuscripts/_find').subscribe((res)=>{
        console.log(res);
    });
 }
```

I'm getting the following error in the browser console -

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:27080/Annotations/Manuscripts/_find' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Any help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`Allow-Control-Allow-Origin` use this chrome extension and enable the cross-origin resource sharing. after it will work.

Comment: Using the extension I get the following in the console -

`Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response http://localhost:27080/Annotations/Manuscripts/_find with MIME type application/json. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.`
the `res` returns as `null`

Answer (score 0):

You can setup backend proxy in your webpack.config.js using http-proxy-middleware .

import "http-proxy-middleware" package in your angular app and set proxy in webpack config as below.

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    proxy: {
      '/Annotations': 'http://localhost:27080'
    }
  }
};
```

For More help you can check devserverproxy section on Webpacks official documentation.